# YCSB low read throughput cassandra

Tags: cassandra, benchmarking, ycsb

The [YCSB Endpoint benchmark](http://www.datastax.com/wp-content/themes/datastax-2014-08/files/NoSQL_Benchmarks_EndPoint.pdf) would have you believe that Cassandra is the golden child of Nosql databases.  However, recreating the results on our own boxes (8 cores with hyperthreading, 60 GB memory, 2 500 GB SSD), we are having dismal read throughput for workload b (read mostly, aka 95% read, 5% update).

The cassandra.yaml settings are exactly the same as the Endpoint settings, barring the different ip addresses, and our disk configuration (1 SSD for data, 1 for a commit log).  While their throughput is ~38,000 operations per second, ours is ~16,000 regardless (relatively) of the threads/number of client nodes.  I.e. one worker node with 256 threads will report ~16,000 ops/sec, while 4 nodes will each report ~4,000 ops/sec

I've set the readahead value to 8KB for the SSD data drive.  I'll put the custom workload file below.

When analyzing disk io & cpu usage with iostat, it seems that the reading throughput is consistently ~200,000 KB/s, which seems to suggest that the ycsb cluster throughput should be higher (records are 100 bytes).  ~25-30% of cpu seems to be under %iowait, 10-25% in use by the user.

top and nload stats are not ostensibly bottlenecked (<50% memory usage, and 10-50 Mbits/sec for a 10 Gb/s link).

```
# The name of the workload class to use
workload=com.yahoo.ycsb.workloads.CoreWorkload

# There is no default setting for recordcount but it is
# required to be set.
# The number of records in the table to be inserted in
# the load phase or the number of records already in the
# table before the run phase.
recordcount=2000000000

# There is no default setting for operationcount but it is
# required to be set.
# The number of operations to use during the run phase.
operationcount=9000000

# The offset of the first insertion
insertstart=0
insertcount=500000000

core_workload_insertion_retry_limit = 10
core_workload_insertion_retry_interval = 1

# The number of fields in a record
fieldcount=10

# The size of each field (in bytes)
fieldlength=10

# Should read all fields
readallfields=true

# Should write all fields on update
writeallfields=false

fieldlengthdistribution=constant

readproportion=0.95

updateproportion=0.05

insertproportion=0

readmodifywriteproportion=0

scanproportion=0

maxscanlength=1000

scanlengthdistribution=uniform

insertorder=hashed

requestdistribution=zipfian
hotspotdatafraction=0.2

hotspotopnfraction=0.8
table=usertable

measurementtype=histogram

histogram.buckets=1000
timeseries.granularity=1000
```

Comment: Throughput is not scaling at all with respect to the number of clients.  With 1 client, we get a set amount of ops/sec.  When running 2 ycsb clients in parallel, each get  throughput / 2 , 4 clients gets throughput / 4.  Have set concurrent reads to 1024, as well as core & max connections in ycsb client to 1024.  nload reveals no change in network traffic when adding clients (expect 2x traffic when going from 1 client to 2).  Traffic is only ~20 Mbits, so definitely not bottlenecked.

Comment: Compacting SSTables had no effect on performance.

Comment: You should be more specific about what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was increasing native_transport_max_threads in the casssandra.yaml file.

Along with the increased settings in the comment (increasing connections in ycsb client as well as concurrent read/writes in cassandra), Cassandra jumped to ~80,000 ops/sec.